# How to deal with multiple devices in this particular situation?

Tags: android, html, css, iphone, device

I try to test a website for different devices.
I only have a iPhone 4 and an iPad 2 to test so for the rest I use chrome to simulate devices.

I notice chrome does things really strange.

For example, on a iphone 5 preview it shows correct but the container is shown really small.

[image]

If I check for iphone 6 plus then the content is drawn way to large. Where I should see 5 rows I only see 2.

This is the same with the iphone 4 preview. But on my real device it shows ok on the iPhone.

[image]

In case it helps, this is some of the css:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    overflow: hidden; 
}

#container {
    display: -ms-flexbox;      
    display: -webkit-flex; 
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}
```

For the client mobile functionality is a top priority. I only have no clue what I should do?

I aslo have this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0">
```

But with or without makes no difference.

If i test other websites with the chrome inspector then some have the same problem and some not. What could I do about this?
I'm totally lost.

Comment: Please don't use `maximum-scale=1.0`...we're not all blessed with 20/20 vision...sometimes we **need** to scale sites to see them properly on mobile.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest possible solution: did you reload the page?

If that doesn't help: Some Websites store data relevant to the view in their cookies. Try clearing your cookies.

Comment: Right, reloading should be good. I already saw a message from Chrome saying that you should reload when you change the device.

Comment: Yeah I reloaded, restarted and rebooted. But I notice there is also a bug, if I go from 4 to 5 then 5 displays correct. If I go from 6 to 5 then 5 displays incorrect. This is with reloading.

Comment: About the cookies, I made the site myself and it does not use cookies.